# KTable vs KSqlDb

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb, ktable

i'd like to understand difference between KTable and KsqlDb. I need two data flows from my "states" topic:

1. Actual snapshot of a state as key-value store
2. Subscription to events of state data changes

I may created compacted-topic and use KTable as key value store with updates for the 1 case. Also i will use consumer to subscribe for state events for the second case.
Is it possible to use KSqlDb for those cases? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use ksqlDB in both cases. ksqlDB benefits from robust database features and simplifies software developing with an interface as familiar as a relational database. For a comprehensive comparison you can read [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-vs-ksqldb-compared/) article.